# XCode set to use Swift 2.0 by default?

Tags: xcode, swift

This could be a *seriously* dumb question, but I have checked in the terminal that my computer is using swift 1.2 right now:

```
$ xcrun swift -version
Apple Swift version 1.2 (swiftlang-602.0.53.1 clang-602.0.53)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0
```

I want to make sure I'm using swift 2.0 in my new projects so I am learning to use things like "guard" and whatnot.

I know I can Edit -> Convert -> To lastest Swift syntax on existing code I've written, but I am wondering **can you set xcode to just use swift 2.0 by default on new projects?**

I find myself getting confused if my code is written incorrectly or if I am simply trying to write swift 2.0 in a swift 1.2 project. I also don't understand, is doing the edit -> convert on each file the correct way to do this?! What if I have a huge project with 100 files!?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The release version of Xcode (6.4) only supports Swift 1.2.  You need to get the latest beta of Xcode 7 (beta 6).  Once you have installed that (and you use it instead of the 6.x version) it will automatically use Swift 2.0.

You may also need to run `xcode-select` from the command line to switch the command line tools to use Swift 2.

```
xcode-select --switch /path/to/Xcode7/beta
```

You might need to run it with `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

By default **Xcode 7** using Swift version **2** (2.x.x) AND **Xcode 6.4** using Swift **1.2**. You can NOT change Xcode 7 to use SWIFT 1.x version and other way around.

If you have installed both Xcode 6.x AND 7.x versions then you have installed SWIFT 1 and 2 version in your computer.

When you check typing  **swift -version** in terminal it provides the default configured SWIFT version (1 or 2) for command line.

If you have both can easily change it from XCODE as well.

- XCODE **->** Preferences
- Select the XCode version in **Command Line Tools** Drop Box Under Location TAB

[image]